# Using automatic prefixing in ConTeXt

Tags: cross-referencing, context

I'm trying to make ConTeXt autoprefixing work, and something is missing here.

Here is an example of code:

```
\setupreferencing[state=start]
\setuphead[chapter][prefix=+]
\starttext
\startchapter[reference=blah,title={Hei}]
Hello world
\placefigure[here][test]
{descr}
{\externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm]}
\stopchapter
\startchapter[reference=blah1, title={Hei2}]
Chapter \in[blah]

Figure \in[test]

Figure by prefix \in[blah:test]
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

I'm getting the following output:

[image: my output]

Obviously, I expect no question marks. I'm referring to the [manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf). Page 235.

I'm using default installation of ConTeXt with texlive from Arch Linux repos. Here is the `context --version` output:

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.01
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2017.05.15 21:48
```

Did anybody use this functionallity? Please help me to find the solution.

Thank you very much!

upd:
tested with standalone ConTeXt from [here](http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/first-setup.sh), the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the ConTeXt reference manual is that it is quite outdated.  In this particular case `prefix` has been renamed to `referenceprefix`.  However, the `+` option still doesn't work.  I asked about it on the mailing list https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/thread/K6Y66EIOZS4A2Z3B5GC2JYVRO5FS7SBN/ (archive link https://web.archive.org/https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/091591.html)

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [referenceprefix=blah] % explicit prefix works :/

\starttext

\startchapter[reference=blah,title={Hei}]

  Hello world
  \startplacefigure[location=here,reference=test,title={descr}]
    \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm]
  \stopplacefigure

\stopchapter

\startchapter[reference=blah1,title={Hei2}]

  Chapter \in[blah]

  Figure \in[test]

  Figure by prefix \in[blah:test]

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Maybe it makes sense also to mention in the mailing list that `\version[temporary]` doesn't work as well. It doesn't show defined labels.