# ConTeXt: getting access to each figure of combination

Tags: cross-referencing, context

I have a combination of figures, and I would like to be able to refer to each figure without hardcoding their descriptions. `\combination` command allows setting automatic labels (a, b, c) by setting `\combination[alternative=label]`. But it is still the mystery for me, how to get access to each figure of the combination.

Here is an example:

```
\starttext
\startchapter[reference=blah,referenceprefix=blah,title={Hei}]
Hello world
\startplacefigure[location=here, reference=test, title={descr}]
    \startcombination[nx=2, ny=1, alternative=label]
        { \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm] }
        { \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm] }
     \stopcombination
\stopplacefigure
\stopchapter
\startchapter[reference=blah1, title={Hei2}]
Chapter \in[blah]

Figure \in[test]

Figure by prefix \in[blah:test]

I want access of the following kind: \in[blah:test:a]
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

So, it would be great to have automatic reference names or at least to have an ability to set references manually. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
\starttext
\startchapter[reference=blah,referenceprefix=blah,title={Hei}]
Hello world
\startplacefigure[location=here, reference=test, title={descr}]
    \startcombination[nx=2, ny=1, alternative=label]
        { \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm, reference=a] }
        { \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm, reference=b] }
     \stopcombination
\stopplacefigure
\stopchapter
\startchapter[reference=blah1, title={Hei2}]
Figure by prefix \in[a]
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Actually, this way is not really fancy, because I have to come up with unique image labels. So better would be to make use of automatic referencing (which [doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432844/using-automatic-prefixing-in-context/432927) for now). Although, according to the [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432844/using-automatic-prefixing-in-context/432927), manual reference-prefixing works, it crashes here, when I set `referenceprefix` to `\startplacefigure`:

```
\starttext
\startchapter[reference=blah,referenceprefix=blah,title={Hei}]
Hello world
\startplacefigure[location=here, reference=test, referenceprefix=test, title={descr}]
    \startcombination[nx=2, ny=1, alternative=label]
        { \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm, reference=a] }
        { \externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg][width=5cm, reference=b] }
     \stopcombination
\stopplacefigure
\stopchapter
\startchapter[reference=blah1, title={Hei2}]
Figure \in[test] -- crashes. Gives ?? in the output.

Figure by prefix \in[blah:test:a] -- consequently doesn't work as well.
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

I see this workflow intuitive, but maybe there is at least some other approach or workaround. Currently, the only way out is to drop `alternative=label`, mark manual letters a, b, c in the comnination:

```
{\externalfigure[IMG_0001.jpg]} {a}
```

And then refer to it by parent label like: `\in[test, left=(Fig.~, right=]a)`. One can set his own reference command, but it is not the point.

Thank you for support!

Comment: As an alternative to your final comment, you can also do `\in{Fig.}{a}[test]`.

Comment: @mickep, thanks. It looks better. Is it possible to adapt this suggestion for the case of defined `\definereferenceformat[infig][left=(Fig.~, right=)]`. Can I insert `{a}` before closing bracket?

Comment: Not implemented, see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Combinations#Referencing